# Low-volatile liquids that 'ball-up' on siliconoxide or perfluoroalkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

This is a very simple and short question. I am looking for liquids that are low/non-volatile at 20$^\circ$C (at least substantially less volatile than water) which have a high contact angle with glass and oxidized silicon (in air) or with a coating of perfluoroalkanes (specifically [Perfluorodecyltrichlorosilane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluordecyltrichlorosilane)).

The requirement on the contact angle is say $\theta>70^\circ$, i.e. the liquid should 'ball-up' a bit. The reason I am asking is that I cannot seem to find any (common) liquids that have both the low-volatility and the high contact angle $\theta$. Does anyone know some examples? Or, if no such thing exists, can someone explain what the fundamental reason is that these liquids don't exist?

Answer (score 2):

Here it comes... mercury.  75-wt% Ga 25 wti%, mp. 15.5 C and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galinstan

in general wet glass.  Maybe ionic liquids,

J. Am. Chem. Soc. 129(13), 3804 (2007), DOI: 10.1021/ja070169d 
Aust. J. Chem. 57(2) 113-155 (2004)

http://www.researchgate.net/publication/233906460_Wetting_of_surfaces_with_ionic_liquids 
http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcis.2008.10.019 
http://ura.unisa.edu.au/R/?func=dbin-jump-full&object_id=63927

http://www.ppmp.pwr.wroc.pl/sorpa/file/eee7c6b05fb9497a9a59507ca0346479/download 
[DMIM][Cl], 1,3-Dimethylimidazolium chloride, is reported 105.9 contact angle on glass.  That might be a typo - it's a huge number for the class of compound.

http://english.cas.cn/ST/BR/br_progress/201106/t20110622_71442.shtml

[image]

Comment: Also consider putting one or a pair of really long alkyl groups on the imidazolium to make it greasy toward glass, and with a bis(trifluoromethanesulfonyl)imide counterion.

Comment: Sulfate appears to be the internal binding energy opposite (very high) of bis(trifluoromethanesulfonyl)imide anion (very low), giving much larger surface tensions.